# PHP let value fixed in a controller page

Tags: java, php, global, var

I'm trying to do a thing in php that I've learnt in Java.
When a user logs in a website a Controller page saves in a private $userLogged var user infos and redirects him in index.php. Now, if he clicks on "profile" I would like that Controller page had in $userLogged his infos still. How I can do it?
 I've done this:
**controller.php**

```
class ECommerce
{
private $checker;
private $errorManager;
private $userLogged;

[...]

function userLogIn($data) {
    $user = new User();
    $this->userLogged = $user->getByEmail($data["email"]);
    if($this->userLogged) {
        if($this->userLogged->checkPassword($data["password"])) {
            $_SESSION["ec_code"] = $this->userLogged->getCode();
            $_SESSION["ec_name"] = $this->userLogged->getName();
            $_SESSION["ec_surname"] = $this->userLogged->getSurname();
            $_SESSION["ec_email"] = $this->userLogged->getEmail();
            $this->redirect("e-commerce/index.php", null);
        }
        else {
            $data["error_message"] = $this->errorManager->getErrorUserLogIn();
            $this->redirect("e-commerce/accedi.php?err=1", $data);
        }
    }
    else {
        $data["error_message"] = $this->errorManager->getErrorUserLogIn();
        $this->redirect("e-commerce/accedi.php?err=1", $data);
    }
}

function seeUserProfile() {
    $data["try"] = $this->userLogged->getName();
    $this->redirect("e-commerce/profilo_utente.php", $data);
}
```

**user_profile.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

echo $_SESSION["data"]["try"];
```

what's wrong?
Thank you before!
Uh this is the error message I receive:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /home/mhd-01/HOST_NAME/htdocs/e-commerce/controller/ECommerce.php on line 110

Comment: i think you need to include the ECommerce class on all the pages you want to use the $userLogged variable

Comment: The error is in ECommerce file!

Answer (score 0):

In user_profile.php you need to include the ECommerce class like Liquidchrome mentioned like so:

```
require('Controller.php');
```

and then you'll need to create an instance of your ECommerce Class

if you want to pass the same data to user_profile.php page you'll need to instantiate the user_profileclass and pass the instance of the ECommerce class you were using to it.

Comment: Mmmmh it's not this the problem.
I access to the infos from the $_SESSION not from the class!